# How to set cookie in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I am facing issues with setting cookie in Android WebView. I am using the following code:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();    
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie(url, cookie); 
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

But it's not working. I also tried by adding headers using WebView's `loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)` method; but still it's not working. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you're trying to pass a cookie from DefaultHttpClient to the WebView, I had the exact same problem yesterday and tried what you tried. This isn't a direct answer to your question, but ultimately what worked for me was fetching the content with DefaultHttpClient and passing the result to the WebView via webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");. Of course this isn't ideal, but is a good enough workaround for now.

Comment: Can you paste an example of the cookie String you pass?

Comment: @althaf_tvm Did you get your solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Cookie sessionCookie = LoginWebView.cookie;
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webview.this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (sessionCookie != null) {
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName();
    Log.v(TAG, "sync cookies: " + cookieString);
    cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookieString);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but still not working. I even added Thread.sleep() for giving some time for cookie manager to set and remove cookies but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The CookieSyncManager is deprecated now, instead use cookieManager.flush(); to update.
See this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html